# R Shiny: Character to date format

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, lubridate

I am trying to develop a Shiny App capable of receiving a .csv file and run a forecast. 
First, I need to import 2 .csv files and transform the Date column from characters to date format.
Them, transform the data frame into a tsibble object to run the forecast.

In a R script this is simply, I would import the file and them simply use:

```
data$Date <- ymd(data$Date)
dados = as_tsibble(data,index = Date)
```

But this doesn't work. I tried many different approaches including the one on the code but I keep getting the `error evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion/options (expressions=)?` where it should be a data frame with the `str()` information.

The expected result is a table with information like this:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   975 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Date            : Date, format: "2017-05-01" "2017-05-02" "2017-05-03" "2017-05-04" ...
 $ Demand          : int  122 124 113 124 126 114 100 121 118 135 ...
```

I can't think of any solution. Any suggestion?

My code:

```
**UI.R**
   library(shiny)
   library(shinydashboard)
   library(fpp3)
   library(fasster)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title = "DEMO Forecast"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Data",tabName = "Data"),
      menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Analysis")
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Data",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Enter the ED demand file",
                    #INPUT
                    fileInput("file", label = "Choose .csv file",
                              multiple = FALSE, accept = ".csv",
                              buttonLabel = "Browse")
                ),
                box(title = "Enter the ED external data file",
                    #INPUT
                    fileInput("file_extra", label = "Choose .csv file",
                              multiple = FALSE, accept = ".csv",
                              buttonLabel = "Browse")
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                #OUTPUT
                box(width = 12, tableOutput("table_data"))
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Analysis",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Date format",
                    #INPUT
                    selectInput ("date_format", h5("Date format"),
                                 choices = list("ymd", "mdy", "dmy", "ydm")),
                    h5("y = year, m = month, d = day"),
                ),

                #OUTPUT
                box(title = "Accuracy Measures", width = 12,
                    tableOutput("table_erro")
                )
              )

      )
    )
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(fpp3)
library(fasster)

shinyServer(
  function(input,output){

    #Import ED demand data
    data = reactive({
      file1 = input$file
      if(is.null(file1)){return()}
      read.csv(file1$datapath,header = TRUE, sep = ",",
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE, dec = ".", na.strings = " ")
    })

    data <- eventReactive(input$date_format,{
      switch (input$date_format,{
        "ymd" = ymd(data()$Date)
        "ydm" = ydm(data()$Date)
      })
    })

    #Import extra data
    data_extra = reactive({
      file_extra = input$file_extra
      if(is.null(file_extra)){return()}
      read.csv(file_extra$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",",
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE, dec = ".", na.strings = " ")
    })

    output$table_data = renderTable({
      if(is.null(data())){return()}
      str(data())
    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many failed attempts I managed to solve this problem using this code:

```
#Change date format 
data_final = reactive({
datas = data()$Date #auxiliary vector 
datas = ymd(datas)
df = data() #auxiliary data frame
df$Date = datas
as_tsibble(df, index = Date)
})
```

basically I create an auxiliary vector (`datas`) with the Date column and transform it into the date format. Them, I copied the data table to another auxiliary variable (`df`) and updated the Date column with the `datas` vector.
Finally, I convert the `df` to a tsibble object.
I hope this helps!